# Change linked data in a chart embedded in Word

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, charts, microsoft-word-2013

I have set up six charts on a page, so that they're all the same size and formatting. But at the moment there are only two distinct charts and each one has three versions. I did this because I didn't want to do the formatting over and over again, and I would have struggled to make it uniform had I done that. The original chart was copied and pasted from an Excel sheet, so the data is still linked back to that sheet called 'Model 2M.xls'. I'm looking for a way to change the link in the four other charts to 'Model 1M.xls' and 'Model 0M.xls'. All these sheets are identically set up, except for the data. Does anyone know a way of keeping everything the same but just changing the link?

[image: Here is the situation]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get a better answer, you could try editing the docx file directly.  You can rename it to filename.docx.zip and extract it and then I believe edit the XML directly (do a search through the extracted files for Model 2M and make your changes) and then zip it back up using "send to compressed folder" and rename the extension back to filename.docx.  To be able to change the extension, you may need to Google "windows show file extensions" (no quotes).

Comment: That's an interesting idea! I've actually just gone ahead and re-sized them all separately. A bit of a hack... but it's done! Thanks for the help